# Why can we transform SDE like that?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

Let's consider the following SDE:

$$dX_t=X_t\mu dt+X_t\sigma dW_t \: \:\: \:\: \:(1)$$

This is shorthand for

$$X_t-X_0=\int_0^t X_s\mu ds + \int_0^t X_s\sigma dW_s \: \:\: \:\: \:(2)$$

My question is why in many books I've seen that people just divide both sides of (1) by $X_t$ to get

$$\frac{dX_t}{X_t}=\mu dt + \sigma dW_t$$

Is that transformation even correct? How can we reach this result from (2)?

Comment: It is just notation; there isn't a way to rewrite $\frac{dX_t}{X_t}$ into an integral form. But it makes us consider that maybe the new RHS of the equation is related to $d(\ln(X_t))$.

Comment: so what that notation means?

Comment: Again, it doesn't really mean anything at all, because there's no way to recast it into integral form. It just makes us (correctly) expect that $d(\ln(X_t))=\mu dt + \sigma dW_t$ plus an Ito correction (which hopefully we can handle). Note that this would follow immediately from ordinary calculus if $\sigma$ were zero.

Comment: So basically all of this mean the same, i.e. are another ways for writing $X_t-X_0=\int_0^t X_s\mu ds + \int_0^t X_s\sigma dW_s$ ?

Comment: Well...ultimately yes, but that perspective doesn't much help us to solve the Geometric Brownian motion SDE. The point is that the RHS of the GBM SDE is really simple after you divide both the drift and diffusion by $X_t$, so one would hope that there would be a process with that differential which is somehow closely related to $X_t$. And it turns out that there is, which is the usual way that we solve the GBM SDE. Tricks like this are how we come up with the substitutions that we use to solve the few SDEs that can be solved in closed form.

Comment: But still, what does this "division" really mean? :( I'm confused. Maybe I'm looking at it too rigorously.

Comment: Yes, you are. Rigorously you "skip" this step and jump straight to calculating $d(\ln(X_t))$.

Comment: Last question. Why this works too: $dX_t=X_t(\mu dt + \sigma dW_t)$, then I can substitute $dR_t=\mu dt + \sigma dW_t$ and use stochastic exponential definition.

Comment: I'd just call that a generalization of this same procedure, rather than a different approach.